# Web scraping using HtmlUnit on an intranet website

Tags: java, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am presently using HtmlUnit to automatically fill forms and click a button on an intranet site. The code is working on internet websites successfully but failing to do so on the intranet website. The intranet website is an asp site, only opens on IE. The code I am using is as follows,

```
final WebClient webClient = new 
WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER,"10.20.30.31", 8182);

    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false); 
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(true);

    System.out.println(url);
    HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);

    System.out.println("HTML page opened");
    HtmlInput searchBox = page.getElementByName("txtFaq");        //this is actual
   searchBox.setValueAttribute(faq);
    HtmlSubmitInput update =page.getElementByName("clear");
    page=update.click();

    HtmlDivision resultStatsDiv =
                            page.getFirstByXPath("//div[@id='resultStats']");
    System.out.println(resultStatsDiv.asText()); 
    webClient.close();
```

On execution it is encountering the following exceptions,

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: it is difficult to tell with only these information. Please look again at the URL and see if it is correct?  Is this code failing at the getPage() method?